# Javascript Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange bug I cant quite figure out, I've built an accordion slider that shows short content intially and when clicked then shows the long content.

At any one time only 1 tab should be open but when 2 opens the short content dissapears.

ive attached a fiddle, can anybody see whats wrong? Is it because they all shgare the same class?

http://jsfiddle.net/2v44c/

Comment: I see no fiddle I'm afraid, please re-attach :)

Comment: Do you have any source code for us?

Comment: An accordion *and* a fiddle - play the irish rover!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

Simplified the JS a little bit and added 1 line of CSS to help with hiding the short content.

http://jsfiddle.net/2v44c/2/